# Is it possible to do appsrc--ximagesink setup in Gstreamer

Tags: python, gstreamer

I want to stream some random bytes to Gstreamer and display it as follows:

```
[Rand Bytes]--[Video source=appsrc]--[Video sink=ximagesink]
```

The following Python code I found [in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7431245/gstreamer-appsrc-works-for-xvimagesink-but-no-in-theoraenc-oggmux) works

```
source = gst.element_factory_make("appsrc", "source")
caps = gst.Caps("video/x-raw-gray,bpp=16,endianness=1234,width=320,height=240,framerate=(fraction)10/1")
source.set_property('caps',caps)
source.set_property('blocksize',320*240*2)
source.connect('need-data', self.genRandBytes)

colorspace = gst.element_factory_make('ffmpegcolorspace') #To remove

videosink = gst.element_factory_make('ximagesink')
caps = gst.Caps("video/x-raw-yuv,width=320,height=240,framerate=(fraction)10/1,format=(fourcc)I420")
videosink.caps = caps

gst.element_link_many(source, colorspace, videosink)
```

However if I remove the `colorspace` part and set `videosink.caps` as the same as `source`'s, it stops working(nothing happens after clicking start).

My question is why is `colorspace` needed here? Is it possible to do just `appsrc--ximagesink` setup?

Answer (score 1):

ximagesink doesn't support x-raw-gray, hence the need for colorspace conversion.

Having said that, the documentation says that ximagesink only supports video/x-raw-rgb, so I'm thinking that setting that caps property on the sink isn't doing much. In fact, looking at the output of the sink pad on ximagesource's get_caps() method, it's still video/x-raw-rgb even after that caps property is set and playback has started. Taking out the line setting the caps property has no effect on the output.

http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-base-plugins/html/gst-plugins-base-plugins-ximagesink.html